# Telerik Data Access One To Zero One association

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-open-access

I am trying to make **One To Zero One** association between two tables in Telerik Data Access, but can't make it work. Here are my tables:

**Student**

- Id (PK)
- Name (string)

**BackPack**

- Id (PK)
- StuffInside(string)
- StudentId (Unique, Foreign key)

StudentId in Backpack references to Id in Student. When I do the mapping for some reason Telerik is making it **One to Zero Many**. I need **One To Zero One**.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the *[Telerik Data Access Visual Designer](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/feature-reference/tools/visual-designer/developemnt-environment-wizards-dialogs-model-tools-designer-designer)* to model your database? If so, in order to create one-to-one association you need to specify that the ID from one table (*Students*) matches the ID from the other table (*BackPacks*). This way each student will have exactly one (or zero) backpack. Please refer to [this documentation article](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/data-access-domain-model/working-with-associations/developer-guide-domain-model-working-associations-one-to-one-default) which demonstrates the approach.

If this is not applicable in your scenario and you have to match the *Student ID* to the *BackPack StudentId* to achieve the same effect you could create one-to-many association and then manually create the unique constraint on the database server side. Alternatively you could switch to *[Fluent Mapping](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/code-generation/developer-guide-domain-model-class-mapping-fluent-mapping)* which allows you to create custom indexes in you mapping.